# How to debug outer executable using Clion

Tags: c++, debugging, ide, clion

I want to debug with `Clion` an executable that was created using outer makefile.
I saw I can choose another executable in `Run/Debug Configurations --> Executable` but it automatically runs my `CMakeLists`, which I don't want to (cause it fails).

I know `Clion` currently doesn't support "import project with existing makefile".

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. using `Cmake`'s `add_custom_command()` and `add_custom_target()` I called my `makefile`
2. In the `Clion` `Run/Debug Configuration --> Executable` I chose the compiled executable from my makefile.

--- Edit ---
1. Example

```
add_custom_command(OUTPUT app_run.txt
    COMMAND /bin/echo "Not building!"
    WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR})
add_custom_target(app_run ALL
    DEPENDS app_run.txt)
```

Comment: can you share your configuration or an example? (like, as a complete piece of two lines of code as they would look like in CMakeLists?)

Comment: Is the makefile app_run.txt, in this case?